# Changing CSS value based on div value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the background of a cell in a css grid based on a value of a div that is pulled from a php database query.I'm using jquery to achieve the same function with another div, but the only difference is the value that is being compared is the same div in the css. Here is the div structure for the html. `box datetime` is a child of `box a`.

```
<div class='box a'>
<div class='box name'><a style='text-decoration:none; color:#444;' href='foobar.com' target='_blank'>Proper Name</a></div>
<div class='box mm'>75.49</div>
<div class='sog'>10.2</div>
<div class='box datetime'>1</div>
```

Here is the function i'm using.

```
$('.datetime').each(function(index, value) {

  var value = Number($(this).text());
  console.log(value);
  if (value < 4)
     $('.a').css('background-color', '#fff');
     else if (value >= 4 && value <= 15)
     $('.a').css('background-color', 'orange');
     else
     $('.a').css('background-color', 'purple');   

});
```

- `.datetime` is a whole number that represents the number of minutes bewteen 2 times.
- `.a` is the css grid cell that i want to change the css properties of.

Right now, it will only turn all of the `.a` background color to #fff. It will not evaluate correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because value is always less than 4 (< 4) and that why fill it with background-color: #fff???

Comment: Sider, no the value can be anything, the example that i copied just happened to be 1. Also, #fff is just a placeholder to see if it's out of place since the page background is black. Thanks for commening!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting styling on all `.a` elements. The last value in the loop determines the value for all `.a` elements. To set them individually for each `.datetime`, get the parent (`.a`) element of each `.datetime`:

```
$('.datetime').each(function(index, value) {

  var value = Number($(this).text());
  console.log(value);

  var $elem = $(this).parent();

  if (value < 4)
     $elem.css('background-color', '#fff');
  else if (value >= 4 && value <= 15)
     $elem.css('background-color', 'orange');
  else
     $elem.css('background-color', 'purple');   

});
```

Comment: yezzz, you are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually Jonathan's answer was better in that the 2nd parameter passed to the function is the element, and also take note of his if/else logic comments

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  var value = Number($('.datetime').text());
  //console.log(value);
  if (value < 4)
     $(".a", '.datetime').css('background-color', '#fff');
  else if (value >= 4 && value <= 15)
     $(".a", '.datetime').css('background-color', 'orange');
  else
     $(".a", '.datetime').css('background-color', 'purple');
```

..if you have a single group you dont need the each

Comment: Please remember to tell the user what the problem is and why this helps. We're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Thanks Erick, but this would just change the CSS for the .datetime grid cell, not the .a . I have edited my question to include how the html is set up.

Comment: Erick, I've added it above. Thanks.

Comment: As you can see, your code is fine, but you must define your selectors correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing value in from `.each` but overwriting the value on the next line.  Also you don't need to check that the value is `<= 4` since you've already ruled out that the value isn't `< 4`.  But I think the reason your code isn't working is because you are changing all `.a` to the color dictated by the last element processed:

```js
$('.datetime').each(function(index, value) {

  var textValue = parseInt($(value).text());
  
  if (textValue < 4) {
    $(value).parent(".a").css('background-color', '#fff');
  } else if (textValue <= 15) {
    $(value).parent(".a").css('background-color', 'orange');
  } else {
    $(value).parent(".a").css('background-color', 'purple');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='box a'>
  <div class='box name'><a style='text-decoration:none; color:#444;' href='foobar.com' target='_blank'>Proper Name</a></div>
  <div class='box mm'>75.49</div>
  <div class='sog'>10.2</div>
  <div class='box datetime'>3</div>
</div>

<div class='box a'>
  <div class='box name'><a style='text-decoration:none; color:#444;' href='foobar.com' target='_blank'>Proper Name</a></div>
  <div class='box mm'>75.49</div>
  <div class='sog'>10.2</div>
  <div class='box datetime'>12</div>
</div>

<div class='box a'>
  <div class='box name'><a style='text-decoration:none; color:#444;' href='foobar.com' target='_blank'>Proper Name</a></div>
  <div class='box mm'>75.49</div>
  <div class='sog'>10.2</div>
  <div class='box datetime'>18</div>
</div>
```